# Pandas access the first entry of a series of matrix

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matrix

I have a pandas df that looks like this:

```py
    beta
0   matrix([[1], [2], [3]])
1   matrix([[2], [3], [4]])
2   matrix([[0], [0], [0]])
:
999 matrix([[2], [1], [3]])
```

And I want to access the first entry of `df['beta']`, idealy either a list or a np array that looks like:
`[1, 2, 0, ..., 2]`

What I have tried so far:

Convert the series to a list of lists

```py
b_t = list(df['beta_t'].apply(lambda x: x.flatten().tolist()[0]))
b_t = [row[0] for row in b_t]
```

This works, but it takes a while in large datasets.

I also tried:

```py
b_t = list(df['beta_t'].apply(lambda x: np.array(x.flatten()[0])))
```

but this results in a series of series and I don't know how to continue from here.

Any suggestions on how I should improve my codes? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not easy test your data, is possible export first 3 rows to dictionary by `print (df['beta_t'].to_dict())` ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need:

```
df['beta_t'].apply(lambda x: x[0][0][0])
```

Or:

```
[x[0][0][0] for x in df['beta_t']]
```

Comment: @anky_91 - Thank you.